# Addition function in Python is not working as expected

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7

I tried to create a function using which I want to do mathematical operations like (Addition and Multiplication), I could able to prompt the values and when I insert the values result is not returning as expect.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5eqMS.png)

**Code**

```
def addition(num1,num2):    
    return num1+num2 def
multiplication(num1,num2):
    return num1*num2

print("1.addition") 
print("2.multiplication") 
choice  = int(input("Enter Choice 1/2"))


num1 = float(input("Enter First Number:")) 
num2 = float(input("Enter Second Number:")) 
sum = float(num1)+float(num2) 
multiply = float(num1)*float(num2) 
if choice == 1:     
    print("additon of {0} and {1} is".format(num1,num2, sum)) 
elif choice == 2:   
    print("additon of {0} and {1} is".format(num1,num2, multiply))
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need the functions nor the `sum` or `multiply` variables, just put the operation in `str.format()`, and you were missing the last position.

```
# def addition(num1,num2):  
#     return num1+num2
# def multiplication(num1,num2):
#     return num1*num2

print("1.addition")
print("2.multiplication") 
choice = int(input("Enter Choice 1/2"))

num1 = float(input("Enter First Number:"))
num2 = float(input("Enter Second Number:"))
# sum = float(num1)+float(num2)
# multiply = float(num1)*float(num2) 
if choice == 1: 
    print("additon of {0} and {1} is {2}".format(num1,num2, num1 + num2))
elif choice == 2:
    print("additon of {0} and {1} is {2}".format(num1, num2, num1 * num2))
```

And know that you can use fstrings (>= Python 3.6):

```
if choice == 1:
   print(f"additon of {num1} and {num2} is {num1 + num2}")
elif choice == 2:
   print(f"additon of {num1} and {num2} is {num1 * num2}")
```

Old-style formatting:

```
if choice == 1:
   print("additon of %s and %s is %s" % (num1,num2, num1 + num2))
elif choice == 2:
   print("additon of %s and %s is %s" % (num1, num2, num1 * num2))
```

Or string concatenation:

```
if choice == 1:
   print("additon of " + num1 + " and " + num2 + " is " + (num1 + num2))
elif choice == 2:
   print("additon of " + num1 + " and " + num2 + " is " + (num1 * num2))
```

Each person does it a different way and it's useful to know all of them sometimes.

Answer (score 0):

You're missing the positional specifier for the result. Since you have three arguments, you need to specify three positions.

```
print("additon of {0} and {1} is {2}".format(num1,num2, sum))
```