# Need information on Basic Python Arthematic operation

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am using Python Version 3.6.4

I was trying to write a basic python code in Jupyter Notebook where I found my code acting funny.

The below given code is working as expected **But** when I change the operation to (+) in the 4th line of code `print( x, '+', y, '=', x+y)` then it is resulting with [Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/250gQ.png).

Question is why is this unexpected behavior happening when there is a change of operator where **multiplication** works fine and **addition** results with error?

```
def fuc(x):
    x = input('Enter the number:')

    for y in range(1,11):
        print( x, 'x', y, '=', x*y)
print(fuc(2))
```

Comment: And please indent your code properly. This is crucial in Python.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [TypeError: Can only concatenate str (not "int") to str (simple Python programme)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52225721/typeerror-can-only-concatenate-str-not-int-to-str-simple-python-programme). Short answer: Multiplication between strings and ints is defined - returns the string concatenated to itself int times. Addition of string and int is not defined

Answer (score 2):

The user input (i.e. `x`) is string. `y` is integer. Multiplication between string and integer is valid python operation. Addition between integer and string is not. Note that I doubt your code with multiplication works **as expected**, i.e. it will not multiply the number, but repeat the string, e.g.

```
>>> '3' * 4
'3333'
```

To deal with the problem you need to convert the user input to int:

```
x = int(input('Enter the number:'))
```

Note that this will not handle any invalid input, e.g. not numeric input and will raise an exception.

EDIT: Include example code snippet:

```
def fuc(x):
    x = int(input('Enter the number:'))
    for y in range(1,11):
        print(x, '+', y, '=', x+y)
        # print(f'{x} + {y} = {x+y}') # in 3.6+ you better use this

fuc(2)
```

output in python3

```
Enter the number:3
3 + 1 = 4
3 + 2 = 5
3 + 3 = 6
3 + 4 = 7
3 + 5 = 8
3 + 6 = 9
3 + 7 = 10
3 + 8 = 11
3 + 9 = 12
3 + 10 = 13
>>>
```

Normally I would use string formatting for the print, but in this case I keep as in the original code

Comment: Agreed with your answer and I tried the way you suggested but didn't work. but when I tried the same with Python2.7 it is working properly.

Comment: I don't know what you have tried, but **it woks** - check my updated answer.

Comment: just looked at your [other question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50799375/addition-function-in-python-is-not-working-as-expected) and there you do convert user input to float and use string formatting. Why don't you do the same here?

Comment: Thank you guys it's working after restarting my Jupyter notebook

Answer (score 0):

you can try this piece of code:

```
def fuc(x):
x = float(input('please enter your desired number'))

for i in range(1,11):#generally i is used as an iterable
    print( "{}*{} '=' ",x*i)
print(fuc())
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Unfortunately, on this occasion, your indentation is wrong. Fixing the indentation causes your code to fail with a TypeError. Fixing that error causes it to output, e.g. `{}*{} '='  12.0`. Finally, the OP's question was "Why is this happening?" which can't be answered with a code-only answer. Could you please read [How to Write a Good Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer) and in future make sure that answers both answer the question and are technically correct. Thanks.